# Converting a String Date to Date Format Error: 'String is not a Valid DateTime'

Tags: c#, string, date, string-to-datetime

I want to convert string format date value to date format ("dd/MM/yyyy").

```
String EntryDate = "24052023"; 

DateTime ResultDate = Convert.ToDateTime(EntryDate);

DateTime ResultDate = Convert.ToDateTime(EntryDate).ToStringShortDate("dd/mm/yyyy");
```

But it's not working. Show error like string not valid datetime.

Comment: A DateTime value does *not* have a format. A format only applies when you convert to/from a string.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution:

```
string exp_date="24052023"; //string date

string ConvertExpDate = DateTime.ParseExact(exp_date,"ddMMyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("dd'/'MM'/'yyyy");

//Result 
ConvertExpDate = 24/05/2023;
```

This code works.